# Pickup config change from Heroku with mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, buildpack

I currently have a `create-react-app` deployed on my Heroku server, and I'm using the `mars/create-react-app-buildpack`.

I would like to be able to change the Heroku `REACT_APP_` config variables on Heroku, and have them used in the React App.

[image: Heroku REACT_APP_ config settings]

Right now, they config variables are only picked up once when I call `git push heroku master` which means I need to redeploy for the config settings to change.

Has someone been able to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is already handled by `@mars/create-react-app-buildpack` with runtimes configuration variables.

You can use them in your react app as follows: https://github.com/mikehanssen/create-react-app-buildpack#runtime-configuration.

Comment: For anyone use typescript, the declaration file I created is as follows:

```
// Type definitions for @mars/heroku-js-runtime-en

/// <reference path="../@mars/heroku-js-runtime-env/index.d.ts"/>

declare module "@mars/heroku-js-runtime-env" {

    function loadRuntimeEnv(): () => any;

    export = loadRuntimeEnv;
}
```